# GCP Dataflow - Throughput gradually slows down, Workers underutilized

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, throughput

I have a Beam script running in GCP Dataflow. This data flow performs the below steps:

1. Read a number of files that are PGP encrypted. (Total size more than 100 GB, individual files are of 2 GB in size)
2. Decrypt the files to form a PCollection
3. Do a wait() on PCollection
4. Do some processing on each record in the PCollection before writing into an output file

Behavior seen with GCP Dataflow:

1. When reading the input files and decrypting the files, it starts with one workers, and then scales upto 30 workers. But, only one worker continues to be utilized, utilization in all other workers is less than 10 %
2. Initially, throughput was 150K records per second while decryption. So, 90% of the decryption gets completed in 1 hours, which is good. But, then the throughput slows down gradually, even to just 100 records per second. So, it takes another 1-2 hours to complete the remaining 10% of the workload.

Any idea why the workers are underutilized? If there is no utilization, why are they not scaled down? Here, I am paying unnecessarily for a large number of VM-s :-(. Second, why the throughput slows reduction towards the end, and thereby significantly increasing the time for completion?

Comment: Your job might be throttled at the "write to output" stage. A possible reason is that you cannot write in parallel. Also, Dataflow doesn't scale down when there are backlogs.

Answer (score 3):

There is an issue related to the throughput and input behavior of the Cloud Dataflow. I suggest you to track the improvements being made to the autoscaling and utilization behavior of workers [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/159748251).

The default architecture for Dataflow worker processing and autoscaling is not as responsive in some cases compared to when the [Dataflow Streaming Engine](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#streaming-engine) feature is enabled. I would recommend you to try running the relevant Dataflow pipeline with Streaming Engine enabled, since it provides a more responsive autoscaling performance based on CPU utilization for your pipeline.

I hope you find the above pieces of information useful.

Comment: That's true...I think, we made WRONG decision to go for a half-cooked product like Beam and Dataflow. It looks like it has so many performance issues. Very funny to see 10  high memory worker nodes processing overall 100 records per second with a CPU utilization of less than 1%.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to implement your solution without wait() ?

For example,
FileIO.match().filepattern() -> ParDo(DoFn to decrypt files) -> fileIO.readmatches() -> ParDo(DoFn to read files)

See the example [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.java#L133).

This should allow your pipeline to better parallelize.

Comment: We did not have the wait() initially. But, then, the dataflow tries to get all the files processed in the same worker, leading to an OOM error. So, we added the wait() to increase the load in the worker, so as to autoscale

Comment: Can you try the above pattern ? This should split work across multiple workers.